# Glossy gradient with android drawable xml

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, xml-drawable

I'm trying to bring out a glossy xml drawable gradient as a background to a layout. I am already using the start color and end color boring linear gradient.

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:startColor="#242424"
            android:endColor="#4e4e4e"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Is there any way to control its range of flow? Please some one help.

**Edited:**

Ok, I have done a little hack around method to get a nice glossy looking title bar,

> Linear Layout (with a gradation - drawable background, specifying all
>   the start and end color values separately) Over this are the icons, (I
>   used Image buttons with transparent BG), and over this another Relative Layout (with may
>   be a drawable gradient or a fixed, grey color - for glossiness -
>   android:background="#20f0f0f0" ) Here 20 is defining the Alpha value.

P.S, This might not be a correct work around, but I'm quiet satisfied with this because switching themes according to clients needs is much faster when compared to 9 patch PNG files (hey, BTW this is just my opinion on it)

And this [link](http://www.dibbus.com/2011/08/even-more-gradient-buttons-for-android/) is so informative on this,

Comment: Did you get  some solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you cant  control its range of flow but instead you can use another property centerColor.
you should try the center color Property  in gradient for glossy background.

i used this in my application .

```
<gradient
android:startColor="#FFF7F7F7"
android:centerColor="#FFCECFCE"
android:endColor="#FFBEBEBE"
android:angle="270"/>
```

hope this will work for you

Comment: Yes, center color is a choice but it will end me up with a 3 color gradient. P.S - I have tried this, but I'm looking for the glossy look to it.